# How do I insert in a <mat-toolbar> a clickable logo with Angular material?

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, angular-material

Is there a way to insert in a `<mat-toolbar>` a clickable logo? I'm using Angular material and I want to insert the clickable image instead of `<span>aPHrodite</span>` in the following html code, in order to intercept the click event on that image.

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        ....
  <span>aPHrodite</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
        ....
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

An image tag with a click listener?

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  ...
  <img [src]="myImageUrl" (click)="myMethod()">
  ...
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use the url of an image. Should I do: `<img url="imageUrl" (click)="myMethod()">`?

Comment: You still use the `src` attribute, just without the square brackets of attribute binding. I hope you don't mind me suggesting this, but I think some kind of course could be really useful to you. Most of them cover this kind of thing, and give you plenty of opportunities to practice. I strongly recommend Max Schwarzmuller's courses (Academind/Udemy).